# Convert to different bases

Tags: rust

Another code for exercism, It is to convert Vec of u32 from one base to another base. Please help to make it more idiomatic, Also if this type of question is welcomed here or not.

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum Error {
    InvalidInputBase,
    InvalidOutputBase,
    InvalidDigit(u32),
}


pub fn convert(number: &[u32], from_base: u32, to_base: u32) -> Result<Vec<u32>, Error> {


    if from_base < 2 {
        return Err(Error::InvalidInputBase);
    }

    if to_base <2  {
        return Err(Error::InvalidOutputBase);
    }

    if number.iter().any(|&x| x > 0 && x >= from_base ){
        return Err(Error::InvalidDigit(from_base));
    }

    let  res: u32 = number.iter().rev().enumerate().map(|(index, x)| x*from_base.pow(index as u32)).sum();
    Ok(convert_back(res, to_base))

}



fn convert_back(number: u32, base: u32) -> Vec<u32>{

    let mut res: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    let mut inter = number as f64;

    loop {
        inter = inter as f64/base as f64;
        res.push((inter.fract()*base as f64).round() as u32);
        if inter as u32 ==0{
             break
             }

        inter = inter.trunc();
        }

        res.reverse();
        res

}
```

Some tests

````
fn decimal_to_binary() {
    let input_base = 10;
    let input_digits = &[4, 2];
    let output_base = 2;
    let output_digits = vec![1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0];
    assert_eq!(
        ayb::convert(input_digits, input_base, output_base),
        Ok(output_digits)
    );
}

fn trinary_to_hexadecimal() {
    let input_base = 3;
        let input_digits = &[1, 1, 2, 0];
        let output_base = 16;
        let output_digits = vec![2, 10];
    assert_eq!(
       convert(input_digits, input_base, output_base),
        Ok(output_digits)
    );
}

fn hexadecimal_to_trinary() {
    let input_base = 16;
    let input_digits = &[2, 10];
    let output_base = 3;
    let output_digits = vec![1, 1, 2, 0];
    assert_eq!(
        convert(input_digits, input_base, output_base),
        Ok(output_digits)
    );
}

fn invalid_positive_digit() {
    let input_base = 2;
    let input_digits = &[1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0];
    let output_base = 10;
    assert_eq!(
        convert(input_digits, input_base, output_base),
        Err(Error::InvalidDigit(2))
    );
}

fn output_base_is_zero() {
    let input_base = 10;
    let input_digits = &[7];
    let output_base = 0;
    assert_eq!(
        convert(input_digits, input_base, output_base),
        Err(Error::InvalidOutputBase)
    );
}

```
````

Comment: It's considered bad form to edit the code in your questions after they're posted. The changes you've made are good, but I'd already started writing an answer!

Answer (score 1):

### Style

These are in order of me thinking of them; not in order of first appearance. Sorry!

#### `#[test]`

If you mark your tests with `#[test]`, then running `cargo test` will run them. If you also mark them with `#[cfg(test)]`, then they'll only be compiled in test mode.

#### Unneeded `collect()`

`cargo clippy` is an invaluable tool. Here, it found an optimisation!

```
if !number.iter().filter(|&x| *x > 0 && *x >= from_base ).collect::<Vec<_>>().is_empty(){
    return Err(Error::InvalidDigit(from_base));
}
```

It points out that `.collect::<Vec<_>>().is_empty()` should be replaced with `.next().is_none()`:

```
if !number
    .iter()
    .filter(|&x| *x > 0 && *x >= from_base)
    .next()
    .is_none()
{
    return Err(Error::InvalidDigit(from_base));
}
```

The compiler's *probably* smart enough to turn this into efficient code,<sup>[[citation needed]](//)</sup> but this code can be made clearer:

```
if number.iter().any(|&x| x > 0 && x >= from_base) {
    return Err(Error::InvalidDigit(from_base));
}
```

#### Unnecessary casting

```
inter = inter as f64/base as f64;
```

can be

```
inter /=  base as f64;
```

and you can get rid of all of the `base as f64` bits by putting

```
let base = base as f64;
```

at the top of `convert_back`.

After a quick pass through `cargo fmt` to clean up the errant spacing and expand the iterator chain to separate lines, this all looks pretty good.

### Algorithm

Your algorithm is, sadly, more limited than it looks. Your use of `as` is a little risky, as casting to a smaller integer truncates it. However, that won't get to be a problem, because as soon as the `from_base.pow` ends up with a number bigger than `u32` can store, it'll panic.

You need some kind of "too big" `Error` variant if you want to handle this gracefully; you could check whether `number.len() > u32::MAX` (otherwise `as`'s truncation could cause issues), and then check whether all the `.pow` calls are guaranteed to work (perhaps with `.checked_pow`?), and then whether adding all the digits together will exceed the bounds of `u32`.

Alternatively, you could make the algorithm convert via base 2³² instead of `u32`s, which would resolve the issue.